# Where is the DbSet <--> Table mapping specified?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, orm

I wrote a class `Patient` which is supposed to be an object representation of my relation. Then I wrote a context class which inherits from `DbContext` and which contains a public property `DbSet` of `Patients`. All right. Now, how do I say to Entity that this `DbSet` should work with `TBL_PATIENTS` table in the database? Where do I configure that?
(well, as you can see i'm very new to .NET and Entity, so any help is appreciated)

Comment: Please paste your code to help you

Comment: Just add `[Table(Name="TBL_PATIENTS"]` attribute. There are other ways too.

Comment: But the attribute goes on the Patient class, not on the DbSet.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Where should that go? In the constructor? Can you please write a sample so that I accept that as an answer?

Comment: Attributes are always place right before the element they belong to. Work through a [few tutorials](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/models-%28data%29) before you proceed..

Comment: OK, so far I've included the `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema` and put the `[Table(Name="TBL_PATIENTS")]` right before the Patient class definition. And now the studio shows me that something is wrong with `Name`

Comment: "something is wrong" is not something you will get help with.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an `EntityTypeConfiguration<Patient>` and initialise it in your `Context` class.

e.g.

`Context`:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    static MyContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<MyContext>(null);
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new PatientMap());
    }
}
```

`Map`:

```
public class PatientMap: EntityTypeConfiguration<Patient>
{
    public PatientMap()
    {
        //table
        this.ToTable("TBL_PATIENTS", "dbo");

        //PK
        this.HasKey(t => t.id);

        //Columns
        this.Property(t => t.forenames)
            .HasColumnName("FIRSTNAMES")
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(50);

        // Relationships
        this.HasRequired(t => t.Ward)
            .WithMany(t => t.Patients)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.Ward_id);
    }
}
```

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696117%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) and [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/165720/Using-the-Code-First-Model-Configuration-Classes) for more information